# Adding intervals to the end of photo names when the EXIF date is the same

Tags: bash

I am working on a script to automate my photo management and am stuck on the last part of the workflow. The script currently does the following...

1. Queries through a given folder to find any images using their file extension.
2. Once it finds a file, it queries the EXIF DateTime field.
3. Using the DateTime field, a folder structure is created in another location with the following syntax. /2016/10.october/10.31.2016/
4. The photo is then moved to the new folder that matches its DateTime. /2016/10.october/10.31.2016/random_photo793958.jpg
5. The photo is then renamed to /2016/10.october/10.31.2016/10.31.2016_01.jpg

While this works fine if only one photo exists for any given day, it simply overwrites existing photos in its current state. I am not sure how to go about building a loop to check if the file exists and changing the _01 to _02 and so on.

I have tried using a While loop but would always get stuck in an infinite loop. Using my current structure, what would be the best loop for doing this?

```
dateTime=`identify -verbose "$2" | grep "exif:DateTime:" | awk -F' ' '{print $2" "$3}'`
eDate=`echo $dateTime | awk -F' ' '{print $1}'`
year=`echo $eDate | awk -F ":" '{print $1}'`
monthNum=`echo $eDate | awk -F ":" '{print $2}'`
monthString=`echo $eDate | awk -F ":" '{print $2}' | sed -e 's/01/01.janurary/' | sed -e 's/02/02.feburary/' | sed -e 's/03/03.march/' | sed -e 's/04/04.april/' | sed -e 's/05/05.may/' | sed -e 's/06/06.june/' | sed -e 's/07/07.july/' | sed -e 's/08/08.august/' | sed -e 's/09/09.september/' | sed -e 's/10/10.october/' | sed -e 's/11/11.november/' | sed -e 's/12/12.december/'`
day=`echo $eDate | awk -F ":" '{print $3}'`
oldPhotoName=$(echo $2 | awk -F"/" '{print $NF}') #strip off last portion of $2 to get the photo name into a variable
fileExt=$(echo $2 | awk -F"." '{print $NF}' | sed 's/./\L&/g') #create variable with the file extension and convert it to lowercase
mkdir -p "$outputDir/$year/$monthString/$monthNum.$day.$year" && mv -f "$2" "$outputDir/$year/$monthString/$monthNum.$day.$year/"
n=01
mv -f "$outputDir/$year/$monthString/$monthNum.$day.$year/$oldPhotoName" ""$outputDir/$year/$monthString/$monthNum.$day.$year/$monthNum.$day.$year"_$n.$fileExt"
```

Comment: Please consider distilling your problem down to an [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: and consider using date formats like `YYYY-MM-DD`. The sort automatically. Need to see your `while` loop in order to diagnose the problem. (Edit your Q to show small sample `while` loop that has the same issue). Good luck.

Comment: Rather than adding an `_01, ...`, consider adding the EXIF timestamp in `HHMMSS` and then `_01, ...` in the event two photos have the exact same date and time. Along with @shellter comment this will allow your directory and files within the directory to sort properly (and tell you exactly when the photo was taken by glancing at the filename). Use a `while test -f "/path/fname"; do ext="${fname##*.}"; fname="${fname%$ext}_$n.$ext"; ((n++)); done` to test for and increment your filename until you create a non-duplicate filename for the folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have tagged your question **bash**. While you can use utilities like `grep`, `awk`, `cut`, etc... to parse the text you need, be aware that each call to a utility spawns its very own process in a new subshell. If you are looping over thousands of files spawning 10 subshells each iteration, that can add up.

There is no need to make a majority of the calls because `bash` provides its own text manipulation routines (e.g. *parameter expansion* with *substring removal* and *substring replacement*, *string indexes* and the like) that can greatly speed things up. You have the same *parameter expansion* available in POSIX shell, but without *string indexes*.

Below is an example of how to handle what you are attempting to do with `bash` builtins as well as showing you how to handle incrementing `_01, _02, ..` in the event of a file conflict. The naming also takes into consideration the comments suggesting you gravitate toward a naming convention that will sort logically. The `exif` tags provide a easily parsable date/time format of `YYYYYMMDD_HHMMSS` (which I show you how to break into individual components below). You can do this any way you like (it's yours), but a collections of the comments would lead to something like the following:

Directories by year, containing monthly sub-directories `01-12`, and then individual filenames with a complete datestamp, e.g.

```
YYYY/
  +- 01/
  |   +- YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS.jpg    # duplicate timestamped files 
  |   +- YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS_01.jpg
  |   +- YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS_02.jpg
  |
  +- 02/
  |
  ...
  |
  +- 12/
```

An example filename would be:

```
/home/david/tmp/2016/10/20161010_163345.jpg
```

If photos taken on the exact same second were encountered, then they would be moved to the same location as:

```
20161010_163345_01.jpg
20161010_163345_02.jpg
...
```

Using *parameter expansion* with *substring removal* is straight forward. The `substring` must match from the end of the string to some point within the string (from either the left or right as shown below). Wildcards, globbing, is permissible:

```
${string#substring}     # remove 1st occurence of substring from left
${string%substring}     # remove 1st occurence of substring from right

${string##substring}    # remove up to last occurence starting from left
${string%%substring}    # remove up to last occurence starting from right
```

String indexes are straight forward as well

```
${string:position:len}  # extract 'len' number of chars beginning at position
```

(you can set the position from the **end** of the string by making `position` negative, *but you must either* (1) leave a space between the `:` and the number (e.g. `${foo: -2:1}`) or enclose a negative `position` in parenthesis (e.g. `${foo:(-2):1}`) )

With that in mind, you can make each component of the date/time stamp available for your naming convention relatively easily, as well as handle splitting of the `path` and `extension`. I have made an effort to comment the code below to help you follow along:

```
#!/bin/bash

fullfn="$1"   # the full filename including: /path/to/your/image.jpg

# exif datetime (original), 
# remove ' Value: ' label, 
# remove all :, translate ' ' to _
datetime=$(exif -t 0x9003 "$fullfn" | \
    sed -n 's/^.*Value:[ ]//p' | \
    tr -d ':' | tr ' ' _)

# validate $datetime is YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS
[[ $datetime =~ [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] ]] || {
    printf "error: invalid date/time from '%s'\n" "$fullfn"
    exit 1
}
dtdate=${datetime%_*}   # isolate YYYYMMDD
dttime=${datetime#*_}   # isolate HHMMSS
dtyear=${dtdate:0:4}    # split YYYYMMDD into YYYY
dtmon=${dtdate:4:2}     # into MM
dtday=${dtdate:6:2}     # into DD

path="${fullfn%/*}"                     # isolate path from /path/fname.ext
fn="${fullfn#"$path"/}"                 # isolate fn from path
test "$fullfn" = "$path" && path='.'    # if no path, set to '.' (or $PWD)
ext="${fn##*.}"                         # isolate ext from fn.ext
test "$ext" = "$fn" && ext=             # unset if no extension present
if test -n "$ext"
then
    lcext=".${ext,,}"    # I like my extensions lowercase
else
    lcext=".jpg"         # if no extension, then its 'jpg' (or leave blank)
fi

## create your directories as desired here
# e.g.
newpath=~/tmp/$dtyear/$dtmon    ## SUBSTITUTE YOUR LOCATION FOR tmp HERE
mkdir -p "$newpath"

# test no duplicate before moving to new directory
declare -i n=1
newfn="${datetime}$lcext"           # YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS.jpg
newname="$newfn"                    # copy of $newfn to update if req'd
while test -f "$newpath/$newname"   # increment 'n' until no conflict
do
    printf -v newname "%s_%02d%s" "${newfn%$lcext}" "$n" "$lcext"
    ((n++))
done
newfn="$newname"

printf "mv %s\nto %s\n" "$fullfn" "$newpath/$newfn"
mv "$fullfn" "newpath/$newfn"

exit 0
```

**Note:** this is just an example that takes a single filename and operates on it as required. You would need to include something similar within your loop that process all the files you would like to sort and move. Also note the `exif` takes a `tag` selection `-t`. Above `-t 0x9003` corresponds to the `Date and Time (Original)` for the image. You can use `exif -l imagename.jpg` to examine all tags available for the image.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./splitexif.sh ~/tmp/100_4423.JPG
mv /home/david/tmp/100_4423.JPG
to /home/david/tmp/2016/10/20161010_163345.jpg

$ cp ~/tmp/100_4423.JPG foo

$ ./splitexif.sh ~/tmp/foo
mv /home/david/tmp/foo
to /home/david/tmp/2016/10/20161010_163345_01.jpg
```

If called again, you would get:

```
$ ./splitexif.sh ~/tmp/foo
mv /home/david/tmp/foo
to /home/david/tmp/2016/10/20161010_163345_02.jpg
```

Look things over and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you for the extremely detailed explanation. I used awk, grep, etc simply because I am most comfortable with those. With that said, your examples enabled me to modify my existing script to remove those with little trouble. I have incorparated your examples into my script and after making a few changes, have it work except for one last thing that I could use some help on understand. The only thing I don't fully understand is the statement in the While loop `printf -v newname "%s_%02d%s" "${newfn%$lcext}" "$n" "$lcext"`. Would you care to break that down for me.

Comment: Oh sorry, `printf -v varname "the format" "the" "vars"` is simply `printf -v varname` where the results of the format string are stored in a the variable `varname`. That way you can take advantage of the `printf` conversion specifiers (in our case `%02d` to always create a 2-digit number, e.g. `01, 02, ...`) It is another tool to add to your bash toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an property (or combination of properties) that make the file unique (or at least sufficiently likely to be unique given your goals), such as the file size (e.g. in bytes) or a checksum, and append that at the end of the filename in the target directory.

This has the advantage that if you actually copy the same file twice, you will not end up with two copies, but rather overwrite the old file with another one that is exactly identical.

For instance, something like :

```
#(assuming variable `file` contains the full path of the file)
#(assuming variable `dir` contains the target directory to move file to)
name="$(basename "$file")"
md5="$(md5sum "$file" | cut -f1 -d" ")"
target_name="${md5}_$name")
mv "$file" "$dir/$target_name"
```

I simplified extension handling by putting the MD5 checksum at the beginning for that example, you might prefer otherwise.

Please note that this avoids any need for a loop, and guarantees that for any set of files, the end result is the same no matter in which order the files are processed.

Comment: That will produce some insane sorting when looking at the files in a directory. Consider *parameter expansion* rather than a hash to resolve duplicates. See my comment to the original question.

Comment: The code I am proposing is not a fully-fledged solution, and yes, it will yield random sorting.  In my solution, I explain that the OP would probably not want to put the "unique identifier" at the beginning of the name, but I left that as an exercise to the reader : my point was the concept of adding something to the filename that would be unique (more or less).  As for parameter expansion, unless I am mistaken you suggest adding a sequential number to otherwise identically named files.  While not "wrong" in any sense, I wanted to avoid that for reasons explained in my post.

Comment: Please note that I mentioned file size (which would be shorter than an MD5 checksum) as another potential "hashing" technique (filename + size should be reasonably unique statistically speaking in real life if you are not talking about insane amount of files).  There could probably be other reasonably unique data to be extracted.